# How can I tell if my votes have been reversed?

Tags: support, voting, serial-voting, achievements-dialog

I'm a bit of a generous upvoter at times.  Perhaps I have a different voting philosophy to others: rather than downvote one post, I upvote all the other posts (those I consider upvote-worthy).

I'm not deliberately selecting users to upvote, although on some of the smaller sites, many of the answers I consider upvote-worthy are by a minority of participants.  So it wouldn't surprise me if I end up giving a single user e.g. 10 upvotes (100 rep) in a day.

Thus I worry about vote reversal: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/)

**Question**: How can I tell if my votes have been reversed?

I'm not aware if this has ever happened in my case, and I'm not sure how I could determine if this has happened.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the FAQ page you linked says, there is no notification for users who engage in serial voting that their votes have been reversed, unless their serial voting involved downvoting answers (in which case they will sort of be notified because they will suddenly get their -1 penalties returned).

There is one way you can tell manually, though: on your user profile, on the "votes" subtab, it lists all the votes you cast, and is updated live whenever you reload it. If you refresh the page one day and all of a sudden many of the votes that were previously listed there are no longer listed there, it means they were reversed. Aside from looking at each individual post, and the above case of downvoting answers, this is probably the only way by which you can tell if a lot of your votes have been reversed. (Note: this only works on your *own* user profile; it doesn't work on others for obvious reasons, even if you're a moderator.)

Comment: Thanks!  I checked on Chinese.SE, and didn't find anything on the first 55 pages (I got bored after that), so my voting is probably not triggering anything.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones, I think it's important to mention that [reversals ***used to*** be clearly shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287585/282094), now you need to watch for +1s (or +2/-10s, for people caught or deleted; running against your account (opposite of what you are asking)).